# Google App Engine Dependencies with Web Test

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webtest

I am attempting to run handler unit tests on my Google App Engine Application using WebTest, however, my application uses vendor.add("lib") in appengine_config.py in order to import libraries that I use throughout the app.

I'm having trouble running my unit tests because webtest seems to not be able to find and import these repos, since they are part of the app's structure and webtest is only emulating one set of it's routes.

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Any way for webtest to recognize the libs? Thanks!!

Comment: install it offline for unit tests

Comment: so, what this sounds like to me is that I would have to include the packages in two different ways in my files in order to use them both online and offline. Or does webtest check my python path?

Comment: you probably can also add the one from appengine SDK to your python path.